# Css transition with keyframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, transition

I want to make a plane move from one point to the other. I want the plane to look like it's going upwards with a smooth transition. The .png file is just a picture of a plane.

Here is my html:

```
<img id="fly" src="fly.png">
```

Here is my css:

```
#fly {
    animation: fly 7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes fly {
    0% {left: 0px; top: 100px; transform: rotate(0deg);  }
    100% {left: 900px; top: -30px; transform: rotate(10deg);}
}
```

Comment: Did you work this out?

Answer (score 1):

Working fine. Just need to declare it as `position: absolute;` first so your animation keyframes have some effect. I changed `#fly` into a `<div>` here because I don't have your image but the code is the same.

```css
#fly {
  position: absolute;
  animation: fly 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fly {
    0% {left: 0px; top: 100px; transform: rotate(0deg);  }
    100% {left: 900px; top: -30px; transform: rotate(10deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="fly">FLY</div>
```